# PHP - Show calculation only when IF statement changes

Tags: php, if-statement

Here is my code:

```
        <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Sr#</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Sale</th>
                <th>Expense</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>    
        <tbody>
            <?php
            $fetch_record = "SELECT * FROM `transactions` JOIN `users` ON `transactions`.`user_id`=`users`.`user_id` WHERE `users`.`user_id`='$user_id'";
            $fetch_record_r = mysqli_query($con, $fetch_record);
            $record_found = mysqli_num_rows($fetch_record_r);
            if ($record_found > 0) {
                $sr = 1;
                $net_total = 0;
                while($records = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch_record_r)){
                    if ($records['type'] == 1) {
                        $net_total = $net_total + $records['sale'];
                    }else if($records['type'] == 2){
                        $net_total = $net_total - $records['expense'];
                    }
            ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $sr++; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-transform: capitalize;"><?php echo $records['description']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $records['sale'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $records['expense'];?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    if (($sr % 2)) { // skip even members
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"></td>
                            <td colspan="2" class="label-info text-center" style="color: #fff;">Total Balance: <?php echo $net_total; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
            <?php
                }
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" class="label-info text-center" style="color: #fff;">Total: <?php echo $net_total; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
            }else{
                echo "<h1 class='text-center text-danger'>No Record Found</h1>";
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Data is coming from database but not the calculations. I want when the transaction type changes from sale to expense then all the sales related transactions should be calculated and vice versa. Just like an balance sheet.I know i have written a wrong logic. but i am unable to tackle the logic. You can understand my question more clearly by seeing the image.[Sale expense calculator example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJY8P.png)

Comment: Are you saying that you want to display a running total after every 2 rows of data?

Comment: No this is what is working now. I want that that every net calculation is shown when $records['type'] changes every time from 1 to 2. Example there are five transactions with $records['type'] = 1, now as soon $records['type']=2 then all the transactions of $records['type'] = 1 should be calculated and result is shown

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary variable to indicate whether or not the `type` value has changed from one iteration to the next.

If this was my code, I'd try to name the columns in my SELECT clause for clarity's sake.
I also think it is sensible to add a `ORDER BY` clause in your query, but I don't know what column name you would like to sort by.

Untested Code:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM transactions a INNER JOIN `users` b ON a.user_id = b.user_id WHERE a.user_id = " . (int)$user_id;  // ORDER BY date (or something?)
if (!$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    echo '<tr><td colspan="4"><h1 class="text-center text-danger">Query Syntax Error</h1></td></tr>';
} elseif (!mysqli_num_rows($fetch_record_r)) {
    echo '<tr><td colspan="4"><h1 class="text-center text-danger">No Record Found</h1></td></tr>';
} else {
    $sr = 0;
    $net_total = 0;
    $type = null;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($type !== null && $type != $row['type']) {
            // type has change from previous and is not null
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="2" class="label-info text-center" style="color: #fff;">Total Balance: <?php echo $net_total; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }

        if ($row['type'] == 1) {
            $net_total += $row['sale'];
        } elseif ($row['type'] == 2) {
            $net_total -= $row['expense'];
        }

        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo ++$sr; ?></td>
            <td style="text-transform: capitalize;"><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['sale'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['expense'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $type = $row['type'];  // update the temporary variable
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="label-info text-center" style="color: #fff;">Total: <?php echo $net_total; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: This is untested, so if I've made any typos, let me know and I'll fix it up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to get the total, of values when the number of entries in the income is more than one right ?

if so, please consider on following approach to get the total of it.

```
SELECT SUM(**column_name**)
FROM **table_name**
WHERE **condition**;
```

You can assign the results to a variable, and populate same using if statements.

You can use if statement to check the number of returned rows are greater than one, to execute above SQL statement, and populate the calculation/ results.

Comment: I want to do exactly what happens in balance sheet